# Filter iphone calls on macbook via python

Tags: python, macos

My brother and his girlfriend just broke up and I want to be by my phone at all times. Problem is, my girlfriend needs to sleep all night because of a medical condition she is recovering from. I don't mind waking her up though if he calls me.

I found this apple support site that describes how to get calls to my computer: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18756?locale=en_US

So here is my question:
How am I able to use python to block all calls from coming through, except from my brother?

Comment: The first is a complicated network issue that isn't easy to answer (you want to transfer signals from a device meant to receive analog signals to a device that's only built for VoIP) - but the second one is fairly simple: filter by phone number. 

This is assuming there in fact is a Python solution to handle voice calls at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than force you to jump through all of the hoops that would come from a pure Python solution, there is a much friendlier solution:

- Get a [Skype number](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA331/what-is-a-skype-number). This lets you receive and make calls to your Skype from personal phones.
- Set up [call forwarding](http://osxdaily.com/2013/03/10/how-to-use-call-forwarding-on-the-iphone/) on your iPhone, and have it forward calls to your Skype number.
- Finally, [set your call preferences](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vXE85bPMOb0J:https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10993/can-i-block-unwanted-calls-to-my-skype-number-in-skype-for-mac-os-x+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) to only allow phone calls from a specific number to go through. Make sure you associate this phone number with your brother.

Any other solution is too much work and will take you significantly longer than the time it will take your brother to get over his girlfriend. Expediency is better than self-sufficiency.

(And if you don't use Skype, [get it](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/))